# 1) DateEdit my selected date is deleted 2) deterioration in form theme

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datetime, devexpress

I have 2 questions.

1. I added the original screenshot of my form as `.jpg`. When my form works, when I click on another form or anywhere other than the form, the image of my form is distorted. I could not find the reason and how to solve it.

   [original screenshot of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9553f.jpg)

   [The deteriorated image of my form (I took the deteriorated part in red square)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlfx2.jpg)
2. After selecting the date with datedit, when I click somewhere else, the dateedit selected value is empty. I tried the binding code in 2 ways, the problem continues. when I delete this code, the problem is fixed.

```
dateAtolyeGirisTarihi.DataBindings.Add("Text", _entity,"AtolyeGirisTarihi",false,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
dateAtolyeGirisTarihi.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", _entity,"AtolyeGirisTarihi",false,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dateAtolyeGirisTarihi.DataBindings.Add("Text", _entity, "AtolyeGirisTarihi", **true**, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, DateTime.Now);
```